# Процессор, ядра и частота процессора

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Делаю БД для телефонов. И мне туда надо поместить информацию о:

- Процессоре
- Кол-ве ядер
- Чистоте

Например, процессор называется "ARM11" и количество ядер у телефона, например, 2, и частота, допустим, 2700 МГц. Может ли быть такое, что название процессора одинаковое, а частота и кол-во ядер у определенных моеделей телефона разные?

Если НЕТ, то я буду делать отдельную таблицу с процессорами, где будут поля: `id`, `name`, `kernel`, `frequency`. А уже в таблице телефонов давать `id` процессора.

Если ДА, то информация о названии процессора, частоте и количестве ядер будет в этой же таблице где и информация о телефоне.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это не технический вопрос

Comment: @korytoff: вопросы о дизайне БД являются техническими вопросами: [проектирование баз данных явно указано](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @jfs согласен, но прочитай еще раз вопрос. Вопрос явно про телефоны и процессоры

Comment: ру stackoverflow под рукой был, спросил. Думал, кто знает))